# Regex to replace a folder name in poll path in java

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a relative path to get the files listed in that folder:

folder name: **ReadFiles**

I just use `File pollFile = new File("ReadFiles")` to read all the files from that folder.

Now the folder becomes **"ReadFiles/201907101418"** and folder name with date range varies all the time.

Is there any way to use regular expression to replace that date specific folder and get all the files listen under it?

Comment: Why not just split on `/`?

Comment: If I split and use it also, the folder name with date range varies all the time and had to use regex to match that

Comment: I still don't see why you can't split? Give examples that would mess this up

Comment: Can you not just read all subfolders of the "ReadFiles" folder? I think there's something missing in your problem description.

You can't really use a regex to select the file you need but you can use one to loop through all the subfolders/files.

really not clear what you're doing though, I think the question needs more elaboration.

Comment: @gnomed The issue is there are number of subfolders inside ReadFiles folder and I need only the folder that matches this reqular expression (20\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}) and I don't want to loop all the folders in it as I don't need them. So, I am wondering whether I canpass 'ReadFiles/(20\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})' as an argument to new File() and read all the files directly from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileFilter to check the name of subfolders to match with a pattern:

```
package be.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f=new File("ReadFiles");
        File[] datefolders=f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.isDirectory() && pathname.getName().matches("20\\d{10}");
            }
        });
        for (File subf:datefolders)
        {
            File[] myfiles=subf.listFiles();
            for (File myfile:myfiles)
            {
                System.out.println("Found file: "+myfile.getAbsolutePath());
                // do your stuff with the files in myfile;
            }
        }
    }
}
```